# Google Analytics inside iframe, multiple embeds on same page?

Tags: google-analytics, iframe, widgets

I have built a widget that other users can embed in their sites as an iframe. I have included Google Analytics inside the widget, so that I can tell when other users are embedding it.

My setup is that each widget has an ID, and I record the ID as a page view.

This works fine - when there is just one iframe in a page.

However, I've noticed that if a user puts multiple copies of my widget (with different IDs) in their page, only the last widget in the page records a page view. The other widgets are not recorded at all.

1. Why is this? I suspect that it may be something to do with Analytics only setting one cookie for my domain?
2. Is there anything I can do about it? I'd like to know each time each widget is embedded, whether on the same page or not.